# Android WebView: Element height returned by JavaScript is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, android, dom, android-webview

I have the following HTML document:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>blah blah blah</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to determine the height of `<div></div>` to adjust my `WebView` height accordingly, which I do the following way:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].scrollHeight
```

Sometimes the value returned is correct, sometimes it is a bit less than actual. I call this piece of JavaScript in `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()` method, so the page should have been rendered by this time.

I also tried `.clientHeight`, `.offsetHeight`, and even `.getBoundingClientRect().height`

Is there any way to get correct and consistent values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the exact value of a style attribute for any element, you can use this

```
// get the reference to the element
var myDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

// get the desired height attribute
var computedHeight = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle( myDiv, null ).getPropertyValue( 'height' );
```

Hope that helps.